# Impact on SEO with NextJS on initial page load, when loading is set to true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a setup with NextJS and Redux, where the initial state of `loading` is set to `true`. After my `init` function is done, it dispatches an action that sets `loading` to `false`, at which point content is rendered on the page.

During this time, as `init` is running, a Lottie spinner is shown, and nothing else.

Right clicking on the page and looking at the source, I obviously see nothing server-sent, other than an html skeleton.

For several reasons, I need the app to first be visited by the user. Content received is conditional on several factors, therefore I can't send content straight from the server on the initial visit to the page.

My question is how much this affects the SEO? I've used several online tools such as [this](https://totheweb.com/learning_center/tools-search-engine-simulator/) one, and I'm seeing this:

[image: img]

At this point, I'm question why I'm using NextJS, when I could just as easily be using ReactJS instead. I'm a little new to NextJS and SSR in general, and I'm not sure how web crawlers work exactly in a situation such as mine right now.